# Create Failed for Login IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0

Tags: authentication

I have Windows 7 Pro(x64), SQL Server 2008 developer edition, IIS 7.5
Trying to create a login for IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 from SSMS->Security->Logins
I am not getting the "Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0"

I am getting this error:

```
Create failed for Login "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0" (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
Windows NT user or group IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 not found. Check the name again.
Microsoft SQL Server, Error 15401
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but is this not a totally differnt error/issue than "Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0"

Any suggestions on how to CREATE this login?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

Do not search for the user account. Type the user name directly into the "Login name" box of the New Login dialog. The format is "IIS AppPool\{poolname}".

If you use the Search feature, the search will resolve IIS AppPool\{poolname} and return COMPUTER\{poolname} to the New Login dialog. COMPUTER\{poolname} doesn't exist, but IIS AppPool\{poolname} does.

Just type it in.

Comment: FYI - This doesn't work on Windows 2008 SP1.  You have to have SP2 installed

Comment: @Mike Haboustak This approach worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Fire up IIS = RUN -> INETMGR -> ENTER

Choose the **ASP.NET v4.0 application pool** from the **Applications Pools** item in the tree view on the left

Choose advanced settings

Under the Process Model section change the Identity value to NetworkService.

Important : Should alway use DefaultAppPoolIdentity for production environments

Comment: How do we use DefaultAppPoolIdentity in production if we don't have instructions that explain how to configure access to Sql Server for that identity and all our development machines are following your instructions and using NetworkService?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, try changing the (Process Model) Identity of your website's Application Pool to use the NetworkService account (or the less secure LocalSystem account).  By default, IIS7 seems to set the Application Pools Identity to 'ApplicationPoolIdentity', instead of NetworkService or LocalSystem.

You can change the ApplicationPoolIdentity from IIS7 -> Application Pools -> Advanced Settings

Under ApplicationPoolIdentity you will find local system. This will make your application run under NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, which is an existing login for the database by default.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the idenity in IIS to localsystem or localservice ....i was not able to run the program i got again the same code.

After a long research i found the solution:

1. open IIS window towards left side expand sites tab
2. within that expand default website tab.
3. now you can find your website name i.e hosted on ISS.
4. Just click on that website (i mean your websitename) as soon as you click on your website towards right of the IIS window you can see "advanced setting" option click on it .....now you will get an new window opened.
5. now set the Application Pool to "ASP.NET v4.0" which by default has "ASP.NET v4.0 DefaultappPool"

Thats all now run you website and see

it might help you

Thank you
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to completely replicate your issue on Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 since everything works okay in my environment per your instructions. I did have the same error when I had mistyped the name of my app pool in IIS but everything fell into place when the app pool name was corrected. I also was able to add the ASP.NET v4.0 identity as well.

I may be reaching a little here, but did you right-click and run SSMS as an administrator? This may not be an issue with UAC on Win 7 but can affect things on the Server versions of Windows. Also, you might try to see if you have the same problem when modifying an NTFS ACL. You should be able to add the app pool identity in an NTFS ACL using the same IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 name as in SQL Server. If you get different behavior, it might have something to do with SQL Server. If not, then there might be a service that's not running on your Win 7 desktop that you need to resolve the app pool identity.