# ASP.NET site works on server through VS but not from client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, iis, gridview

I've a MS Windows 2012 Server running VS Pro 2013 ASP.NET 4.5

The website runs fine when I open VS and run it through there on the server.

However if I create a WS in IIS and copy the exact files into IIS certain parts won't work when I run it from my client machine.

Application pool for the website in IIS is 4.5.

One part that won't work is an autocomplete extender on a textbox and another part is a edit link in a gridview that doesn't fire.

Most everything else seems ok though.

thanks
P

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="SearchCustomers" 

                            MinimumPrefixLength="2"

                            CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10" 

                            TargetControlID="txtCustomer"

                            ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false" OnClientItemSelected = "ClientItemSelectedNewIssueCustomer">

                        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: It is hard to find the issue with the code provided but assuming there is a database, can your application communicate with it successfully?

Comment: any error ? ..try to put in qyour webconfig the customError=Off

Comment: @Mahdi yes it pulls the AutoComplete data from a DB but it's still the same server running the code. Not sure that'd be it?

Comment: @federico scamuzzi no error unfortunately.  customErrors was set to off. thanks

Comment: @PeteWhelan are you sure that your connection string is correct?

Comment: @Mahdi so it works when I'm logged into the server and I run it from VS. It doesn't work when I create a site in IIS and run that url from my machine.

Comment: @PeteWhelan is you DB SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `ApplicationPoolIndetity` to your database login. According to the [documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/):

- Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and connect to the SQL Server
- Open the Security folder at the server level and not the security folder for the database
- Right click on the logins and select New Login
- For the login, type IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName and DO NOT CLICK SEARCH and select OK (If a search is executed, it will resolve to an account with `ServerName\AppPool` Name and SQL will be unable to resolve the account’s SID since it is virtual)
- Select the defaults for the account and select OK to close dialog

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Create failed for Login 'IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: Good! That can be it. Have you googled this error? There is a couple of answers on SO.

Comment: Great thanks I used this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154959/create-failed-for-login-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0 Fire up IIS = RUN -> INETMGR -> ENTER

Choose the ASP.NET v4.0 application pool from the Applications Pools item in the tree view on the left 

Choose advanced settings 

Under the Process Model section change the Identity value to NetworkService.

Important : Should alway use DefaultAppPoolIdentity for production environments